# ACS raster file in QGIS at wrong place

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system, esri-ascii-raster

I am working with QGIS 3.30 and the project in located in Switzerland. My goal is to import a ACS raster file but the problem is that it is located in the Atlantic ocean and not in Switzerland.

My workflow:

- Set up QGIS project in EPSG2056 and a couple layers
- Add the ACS raster file via Layer > Add layer > Add raster layer

The layer displays correctly with all the data and values but not at the correct place. Also, there is the sign in the layer panel saying that the layer has no coordinate system set. I tried to set it to CH1903+ LV95, then WGS84 UTM 32N, then WGS84 but it is still located wrong. I also tried changing the project's CRS **after** loading the ACS layer but **before** assigning it a coordinate system, still doesn't work.

The data was downloaded from the Swiss Federal Office of Environment: [FOEN - Mean Runoff](https://www.bafu.admin.ch/bafu/en/home/topics/water/state/maps/geodata/mean-monthly-and-annual-runoff/mean-monthly-and-annual-runoff-depths.html)

This is what the header and first lines are:

```
ncols               697
nrows               442
xllcorner    485500.000
yllcorner     75300.000
cellsize       500.0000
nodata_value -9999.0000
```

The X and Y seem to be somewhere north of Switzerland, in latitude-longitude, just with the decimal out of place.

### EDIT

Edited link to the correct DEM.

The layer is in the older coordinate system of Switzerland, **EPSG 21781**. I am still not sure what the xllcorner and yllcorner values are but the layer is now at the correct place.

Comment: If the coordinates are in latitude-longitude then WGS84 is probably the correct choice. The project CRS does not matter, QGIS can handle multiple CRS at once.

Comment: Your excerpt does not include any data so what does "decimal out of place" mean?

Comment: Setting the layer CRS to WGS84 doesn't work, it makes the layer disappear. I am talking about the xllcorner and yllcorner, if lat/long decimal it should be 48.5500 and 7.5300. But changing the decimal's place doesn't make any difference.

Comment: What file are you talking about? The linked web page has a zip download with a Shapefile inside and there is no issue with the projection of it.